# How to enable systemd on Dockerfile with Ubuntu18.04

Tags: docker, ubuntu, systemd

I know Systemd is not recommended on Docker containers but is it possible?

I have staging/prod environments on Ubuntu 18.04 cloud VMs deployed with Ansible;

My current dev environment is a Ubuntu 18.04 `Vagrantfile` that uses the same Ansible `playbook.yml` of staging/prod

Now I'm trying to replace the `Vagrantfile` with a `Dockerfile` for development but the Ansible `playbook.yml` fails when applying systemd modules. I would like to have `systemd` on my dev environment as well so that I can test changes on my `playbook.yml` local. Any idea how I can do it?

If I try to build with `Dockerfile` and `playbook.yml` as below, I get an error `Failed to find required executable systemctl in paths`.

If I add `RUN apt-get install systemd` to `Dockerfile` nd try to build, I get an error `System has not been booted with systemd as init system`

Sample `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app

# Install Python3 pip used to install Ansible
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  python3-pip \

# Install Ansible
RUN pip3 install --trusted-host pypi.python.org ansible
RUN ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i inventory

EXPOSE 80
```

Sample `playbook.yml`:

```
---
- name: Ansible playbook to setup dev environment 
  hosts: all
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: "/usr/bin/python3"
    debug: True
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  tasks:
    - name: Copy App Gunicorn systemd config
      template:
        src: app_gunicorn.service
        dest: /etc/systemd/system/

    - name: Enable App Gunicorn on systemd
      systemd: state=started name=app_gunicorn
```

Sample `inventory`:

```
docker-dev ansible_host=localhost ansible_connection=local
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's a perfect example where the [docker-systemctl-replacement](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement) script should be used.

It has been developed to allow ansible scripts to target both virtual machines and docker containers. You do not need to enable a real systemd, just overwrite /usr/bin/systemctl in operating systems that are otherwise under systemd control. The docker container will then look good enough for ansible, whereas I am more used to use the general 'service:' module instead of the specific 'systemd:' module.

Comment: That's why the docker-systemctl-replacement script can be also installed as the docker-entrypoint script - it will then start all enabled services in the container. Upon "docker stop" it will also "systemctl stop" all those services correctly before exiting the container itself. (Effectively, systemctl.py is both a service manager and an init-daemon).

Comment: Ah, I hadn't realized from a brief glance that it would actually parse systemd units and emulate the various settings in order to provide the appropriate environment. Neat!

Comment: By the way, some working examples can be found at https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-images

Comment: The suggested `docker-systemctl-replacement` worked perfectly!
All I had to do was to download `systemctl3.py` from that repo and add it to my Dockerfile as `COPY deploy/environments/dev-docker/files/systemctl3.py /usr/bin/systemctl` and `RUN test -L /bin/systemctl || ln -sf /usr/bin/systemctl /bin/systemctl`

Comment: Note, however, that this script cannot be used in commercial (closed source) projects because of the EUPL license.

Comment: @BojanP.  - always ask the copyright holder if you are unsure. In most cases the EUPL is not a barrier but may be you are thinking of something special.

Comment: systemd has support for running inside of containers. why not use that proper support instead of installing a gross hack?

Comment: The container runtimes have learned only later to support systemd, I think podman since 2021. Actually, it took far longer than I expected.

Answer (score 2):

If its an option you can also start from a docker image with `systemd`already enabled as [this one available for ubuntu 18.04](https://hub.docker.com/r/jrei/systemd-ubuntu), and [see also here.](https://github.com/solita/docker-systemd)

Here is an example dockerfile where we start from this image and install python3.8 for our app needs:

```
FROM jrei/systemd-ubuntu


# INSTALL PYTHON
RUN apt-get update -q -y
RUN apt-get install -q -y python3.8 python3-distutils curl libpq-dev build-essential python3.8-dev
RUN rm /usr/bin/python3
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python3
RUN curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
RUN python3.8 get-pip.py
RUN pip3.8 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3.8 install -q -r requirements.txt

RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 10
ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:."

### then setting the app needs and entrypoint
```

Comment: Thanks. "jrei/systemd-ubuntu" is something that helped to resolve "System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate."

Solution shared for others.

Comment: This one works perfectly https://hub.docker.com/r/jrei/systemd-ubuntu as suggested. Though I am having troubles in mapping the docker run command into a Kubernetes yaml. Any insights?